# My custome list view not update with new data

Tags: android-listview, notifydatasetchanged

Hello I created a custom list view and for update used notifyDataSetChanged() method but my list not updated. please help me.

this is my source code

```
public class fourthPage extends ListActivity {
ListingFeedParser ls;
List<Listings> data;
EditText SearchText;
Button Search;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ProgressDialog progDialog;
private int pageCount = 0;
String URL;
ListViewListingsAdapter adapter;
Message msg;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    URL = b.getString("URL");
    Log.i("Ran->URL", "->" + URL);
    MYCITY_STATIC_DATA.fourthPage_main_URL = URL;
    final ListingFeedParser lf = new ListingFeedParser(URL);
    Search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
    SearchText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(SearchText.getWindowToken(), 0);
    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

    try {
        progDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "",
                "Loading please wait....", true);
        progDialog.setCancelable(true);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    data = lf.parse();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                msg = new Message();
                msg.what = 1;
                fourthPage.this._handle.sendMessage(msg);

            }
        }).start();

        Search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SearchText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
                if (SearchText.getText().toString().equals(""))
                    return;
                CurrentLocationTimer myLocation = new CurrentLocationTimer();
                LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult() {
                    @Override
                    public void gotLocation(final Location location) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                location.getLatitude() + " "
                                        + location.getLongitude(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        String URL = "http://75.125.237.76/phone_feed_2_point_0_test.php?"
                                + "lat="
                                + location.getLatitude()
                                + "&lng="
                                + location.getLongitude()
                                + "&page=0&search="
                                + SearchText.getText().toString();
                        Log.e("fourthPage.java Search URL :->", "" + URL);
                        Bundle b = new Bundle();
                        b.putString("URL", URL);
                        Intent it = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                fourthPage.class);
                        it.putExtras(b);
                        startActivity(it);
                    }
                };
                myLocation.getLocation(getApplicationContext(),
                        locationResult);
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "No data available for this request", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
}

private Handler _handle = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        progDialog.dismiss();
        if (msg.what == 1) {
            if (data.size() == 0 || data == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "No data available for this request",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            adapter = new ListViewListingsAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.layout.list1, R.id.title, data, mInflater);               
            setListAdapter(adapter);                
            getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Error in retrieving the method", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

    }
};

public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    // remember i m going from bookmark list
    MYCITY_STATIC_DATA.come_from_bookmark = false;
    Log.i("4thPage.java -  MYCITY_STATIC_DATA.come_from_bookmark",
            "set false - > check" + MYCITY_STATIC_DATA.come_from_bookmark);
    Listings sc = (Listings) this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    if (sc.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("SEE MORE...")) {
        pageCount = pageCount + 1;
        final ListingFeedParser lf = new ListingFeedParser((URL.substring(
                0, URL.length() - 1)) + pageCount);
        try {
            progDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "",
                    "Loading please wait....", true);
            progDialog.setCancelable(true);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    data.remove(data.size() - 1);
                    data.addAll(lf.parse());

                    Message msg = new Message();
                    msg.what = 1;
                    fourthPage.this._handle.sendMessage(msg);

                }
            }).start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            pageCount = pageCount - 1;
            // TODO: handle exception
            Toast newToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Error in getting Data",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    } else {
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putParcelable("listing", sc);
        Intent it = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                FifthPageTabbed.class);
        it.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(it);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    setResult(0);
    finish();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    Log.e("RESUME:-)", "4th Page onResume");
    try {           
        //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //setListAdapter(adapter);
        //getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("EXCEPTION in 4th page",
                "in onResume msg:->" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not re-create the object of ArrayList or Array you are passing to adapter, just modify same ArrayList or Array again. and also when array or arrylist size not changed after you modify adapter then in that case notifydatasetchange will not work.

In shot it is work only when array or arraylist size increases or decreases.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Android are you targeting? The latest version seems to have revised how notifyDataSetChanged() works. If you target sdk 11 it might work?

Also, there seems to be a different (and very thorough answer) to this question in another post:
[notifyDataSetChanged example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example/5092426#5092426)